# In elastic search how to query a name field values in insensitive case?

Tags: java, spring-data-elasticsearch

Suppose i have a field name called "firstname" . Now if i want to query on field "firstname" , is it possible to search text with insensitive case even if I didn't configure that in the settings. I am using spring data elastic search.

```
@Field(type=FieldType.String, index=FieldIndex.not_analyzed )
private String firstname;
```

Thank you!!